# How to rename numeric observation values as text/name in a single variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Trying to rename recorded observation values for specific variable "cyl" in mtcars. The observations record as one of three numeric values within the "cyl" column (4,6,or 8). I want to correlate these numeric observation values with the text names "Four Cylinder", "Six Cylinder", and "Eight Cylinder".

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mtcars = mtcars |>
  mutate(  cyl = factor(
    cyl,
    levels = c(4,6,8),
    labels = c(
      "Four Cylinder",
      "Six Cylinder",
      "Eight Cylinder"
    )
  )
) ggplot(mapping=aes(geom_bar()) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))
```

Not quite sure what the problem is.  It gave me this error message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  )
) ggplot"
```

Comment: You’ve missed a pipe between your `mutate` and your `ggplot`. Your `ggplot` syntax is incorrect too. Check the online doc for examples that are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying I would highly recommend taking a look at the [ggplot2 website](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) for a better handle on the coding style you should use. As @Limey pointed out in their comment, you have some basic syntax errors as well. You may benefit from looking at [Hadley Wickham's tidyverse style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/) for better coding style to make it easier to identify these errors.

I'm assuming you are looking for something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars |>
  mutate(
    cyl = factor(
      cyl,
      levels = c(4, 6, 8),
      labels = c(
        "Four Cylinder",
        "Six Cylinder",
        "Eight Cylinder"
      )
    )
  ) |>
  ggplot(
    mapping = aes(x = cyl)
  ) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is really what I was looking for.  I appreciate your time in putting that together.  I will follow your suggestions and review the tidyvers and ggplot guide.  THANKS!!

Comment: @RodDog420 No problem! If it helped you please mark it as accepted for future users